# Ideas to make this code less repettitive?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, refactoring

heres a rundown of the component in question

```
export default () => {
  const { currentUser, logout } = useAuth();
  const [sideBarOpen, setSideBarOpen] = useState(false);
  const theme = useTheme();
  const classes = useStyles();
  const isSmall = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("sm"));
  const history = useHistory();

  const toggleSideBar = () => {
    setSideBarOpen(!sideBarOpen);
  };

  const handleLogout = () => {
    setSideBarOpen(!sideBarOpen);
    logout();
    history.push("/login");
  };

  return (
    <AppBar position="static" className={classes.root}>
      <Toolbar>
        <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
          Chatter
        </Typography>
        {isSmall ? (
          <>
            <IconButton color="inherit" onClick={toggleSideBar}>
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Drawer
              anchor="right"
              open={sideBarOpen}
              onClose={toggleSideBar}
              className={classes.sideBar}
            >
              <List className={classes.drawerList}>
                <ListItemLink
                  primary="login"
                  to="/login"
                  icon={<LockOpenIcon />}
                  onClick={toggleSideBar}
                />
                <Divider />
                <ListItemLink
                  primary="signup"
                  to="/signup"
                  icon={<ArrowUpwardIcon />}
                  onClick={toggleSideBar}
                />
                {currentUser && (
                  <Button
                    onClick={handleLogout}
                    color="primary"
                    variant="contained"
                  >
                    Logout
                  </Button>
                )}
              </List>
            </Drawer>
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Link to="/signup">
              <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
                Sign up
              </Button>
            </Link>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleLogout}>
              {currentUser ? "Logout" : "Login"}
            </Button>
          </>
        )}
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
};
```

im wondering how I can go about not repeating the links twice for mobile and desktop because they have 2 separate navigations, mobile has the sidebar and bigger has a legit navbar. maybe theres a way to do this with material ui? maybe theres a good solution with just react? any help will be appreciated alot thank you (there only 2 links now but later there will be quite a bit more)

Answer (score 1):

There would be different possible approaches. You need to define which proberties, styles or code must be different, and which parts can be reused. E.g. I'm not sure if `ListItemLink` can be combined with `Link` in your use case, or if the Buttons should look the same or have e.g. a different size, ...

#### separating components

I try to explain steps that would lead to a solution.
You probably want to skip some steps and come to the same result (but indeed I sometimes just start coding this way):

1. First, I would make two separate components for large and small.
2. Create e.g. a `GenericLink` component and a `GenericButton` component.
3. Add all the code to `GenericLink` and `GenericButton` that is necessary for one of the sizes, e.g. large, and make it work.
4. "Debug" the other size, e.g. small, by adding properties and code that is necessary, to make it work.
5. Implement necessary properties and conditions (like e.g. `size={'small'}` and `icon={ size === 'small' ? null : <ArrowUpwardIcon />}`)

Somewhere on the way you now likely have either found a good solution for your specific use case, or you found that it just doesn't work and you indeed *need* separate components.

#### pass data instead of JSX

Instead of wrinting each `<Link ...>` component as JSX, you can store the list as an array like this:

```
const links = [
  { primary: "login", to: "login", icon: <LockOpenIcon />, onClick: toggleSideBar },
  ...
]
```

You can pass this data to a separate component like e.g. `<GenericList list={ list } size={'small'} />`. This way you can use the same data to generate the big list and the small list.